# Trigger places_changed in Google maps from submit button

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am wanting to trigger my `placed_changed` function when a submit button is clicked.  So here is what I have, I have a `searchbox` I assign using `google.maps.places.SearchBox` and once I click enter with the search box on focus it triggers the event:

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(searchBox, 'places_changed', function() {
    runMainPopulation(searchBox.getPlaces());
  });
```

Which runs the next function.  Now what I am trying to do is get this function to run once I click a `search button` or I click enter on my `searchbox`.

Suggestions, thoughts?

Comment: Does `google.maps.event.trigger(searchBox,'places_changed')` not work?

Comment: @geocodezip No it does not

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I figured it out.

I had to initialize the `Google searchBox` via `google method` post.

For instance:

```
$(".submit-search").bind('click', function() {

    input.focus(); 
    var e = jQuery.Event("keydown");
    e.which = 13; // # Some key code value
    $(input).trigger(e);
    google.maps.event.trigger(searchBox, 'place_changed');
});
```

This would not work, I am not to sure as to why but it doesn't.  `submit-search` is the button next to `searchBox` also defined as `input`.

Now if I initialize my input trigger focus and click through `google.maps.event.trigger` it works perfect:

```
$(".submit-search").bind('click', function() {
    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'focus')
    google.maps.event.trigger(input, 'keydown', {
        keyCode: 13
    });
  });
```