# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-places-api, google-places, typeerror

I have gotten google auto-complete to work, but just in case the user doesn't select the autocomplete, I am trying to submit the address to Google and retrieve the latitude and longitude myself. 
The issue I am having is when I submit without using autocomplete I am getting Uncaught

> TypeError:
>
> Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined and Uncaught
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'location' of undefined (none of my
>   console.logs are triggered).

If I submit with autocomplete I still get Uncaught

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'geometry' of undefined

even though the autocomplete did work to get the address with the lat and long.

My Html

```
<form method="GET" id="my-form" action="/search" onsubmit="check()">
<input class="form-control" id="getaddy" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="term" onFocus="geo()">
<input id="latitude" type="hidden" name="latitude">
<input id="longitude" type="hidden" name="longitude">
</form>
```

I call `geo()` autocompleting, but in case they don't use the autocomplete, I try to catch it on submit with my check() function. Here is my JS

```
function check() {
let latitude = document.getElementById("latitude").value;
if (latitude) {
     console.log(latitude);
  } else {

let term = $("#getaddy").val();

$.ajax({
    url: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="+encodeURIComponent(term) +"&key=GOOGLEKEY",
    type: 'get',
    success: function(data) {
        if (data.status === 'OK') {
            // Get the lat/lng from the response
            let lat = data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
            let lng = data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

            console.log("pass");

        }
    },
    error: function(msg) {
        console.log("fail");
    }
});
    return true;
}
}


function geo() {

  autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(
    (document.getElementById('getaddy')), {
      types: ['geocode']
    });
  autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', addlatlong);
}
function addlatlong() {

var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

var latitude = place.geometry.location.lat();
var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();

document.getElementById("latitude").value = latitude;
document.getElementById("longitude").value = longitude;
}
```

Thank you so much for any help!

Comment: So, you already have the two property values `latitude` and `longitude`, and you want to use the two values to get address but getting error message like that?

Comment: OMG, the update edit...

Comment: If they use the autocomplete in my input <input class="form-control" id="getaddy" type="text" placeholder="Search..." name="term" onFocus="geo()"> then yes I get the latitude and longitude. But if they just enter an address into the field without selecting from the autocomplete list, then I don't get the latitude and longitude. That is why I have the check() function that looks to see if I got the latitude. If I didn't then I am trying to submit the address to google to get the latitude and longitude back.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have the two property values `latitude` and `longitude`, I suggest you to use this code (provided by Google) to get address (*not using jquery ajax*):

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder;
var latlng = { lat: latitude, lng: longitude };

geocoder.geocode({ 'location': latlng }, function (results, status) {
    if (status === 'OK') {
        if (results[0]) {
            var address = results[0].formatted_address);
            console.log(address);
        } else {
            console.log('No results found');
        }
    } else {
        console.log('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
});
```

Source: [Reverse Geocoding (Address Lookup)](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geocoding#ReverseGeocoding)

If they don't submit the request, you can try to use jquery to caugh the event when the `searchBox` lost the focus (`focusout`), then calling event `places_changed` to get the `latitude` and the `longitude`.

Source: [Places Search Box](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox)

Source: [Trigger places_changed in Google maps from submit button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27829792/trigger-places-changed-in-google-maps-from-submit-button)

Comment: I only get the latitude and longitude if the user selects their address from the autocomplete list. If the user just enters an address by hand into the form, then I don't get the latitude or longitude.

Comment: @ChrisGrim I've updated the answer to get `latitude` and `longitude` values when user doesn't submit the request.